# rsync: change_dir "/home/Sources//account@sub.inmotionhosting.com/home/account" failed: No such file or directory (2)

Tags: ssh, bash, scripting, rsync, database-backup

When run this command to make backup database file from remote server, I face the below reasult but I do not know what is the issue. The command I run on my local ubuntu server to git file from inmotionhosting.com

rsync -h --progress --stats -r -tgo -p -l -D --update --delete-after --protect-args -e "ssh -i /location/to/file.pem" account@sub.domain.com:home/account/file.any /local/location/to/store/file/

rsync: change_dir "/home/Sources//account@sub.inmotionhosting.com/home/account" failed: No such file or directory (2)

Number of files: 0
Number of created files: 0
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 0
Total file size: 0 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 0
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 20
Total bytes received: 11

sent 20 bytes  received 11 bytes  62.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]

Please advice :)

Answer (score 1):

You need the `/` before `home`

`rsync -h --progress --stats -r -tgo -p -l -D --update --delete-after --protect-args -e "ssh -i /location/to/file.pem" account@sub.domain.com:/home/account/file.any /local/location/to/store/file/`

Comment: Thank you for your interest, I was not able to connect because the port was wrong,, May I ask how to add the port to the command?

Comment: Your original command failed because you had the wrong path, if it was the wrong port you would have seen `Connection refused` or a timeout. To add the port you would just need to add it to the ssh section of your command `rsync -h --progress --stats -r -tgo -p -l -D --update --delete-after --protect-args -e "ssh -p [port number] -i /location/to/file.pem" account@sub.domain.com:/home/account/file.any /local/location/to/store/file/ `